# How to reduce the space between the axes and the first and last bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, subplot

There is a  big space between the border/x-axe of the graph and the first and last bar in a bar plot in pyplot (red arrows in the first picture). In the image below, it looks fine in the graph on the left, but it's wasting a lot of space in the graph on the right. The larger the graph, the larger the space.

[image]

See how much space is wasted in the second picture:

[image]

Any idea how to fix that?

The code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
grid = plt.GridSpec(figsize[1], figsize[0], wspace=120/figsize[0])
plt.suptitle(feature.upper())

# NaN plot
plt.subplot(grid[:, :2])
plt.title('Présence')
plt.ylabel('occurences')
plt.bar([0, 1], [df.shape[0] - nan, nan], color=['#4caf50', '#f44336'])
plt.xticks([0, 1], ['Renseigné', 'Absent'], rotation='vertical')

# Distrib plot
plt.subplot(grid[:, 2:])
plt.title('Distribution')
x_pos = [i for i, _ in enumerate(sizes)]
plt.bar(x_pos, sizes)
plt.xticks(x_pos, labels, rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

`df` is my pandas DataFrame, `nan` the amount of null value for the feature I'm plotting, `sizes` is the number of occurrences for each value, and `labels` are the corresponding label's value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`plt.margins(x=0, tight=True)`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.margins.html).

The default margins are `0.05` which means that 5% of the distance between the first and last x-values is used as a margin. Choosing a small value such as `plt.margins(x=0-01, tight=True)` would leave a bit of margin, so the bars don't look glued to the axes.

In some situations wider margins are desired. For example when drawing only two very narrow bars. So, the exact value for a plot to look nice depends on multiple factors as well as on personal preferences.

Note that `plt.margins` is best called after the last function that adds elements to the plot.

Also note that `plt.xlim` has a similar function of changing the drawing limits. Here is an example that sets `xlim` to have the same distance between the axes and the bars as between the bars themselves.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(12, 3))
for ax in axes:
    width = 0.4
    ax.bar([0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 5], width=width, color='turquoise')
    if ax == axes[0]:
        ax.margins(x=0.01)
        ax.set_title('1% margins')
    elif ax == axes[1]:
        ax.margins(x=0.1)
        ax.set_title('10% margins')
    else:
        ax.set_xlim(-1+width/2, 3-width/2)
        ax.set_title('setting xlim')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: It works fine, I have to place it after the second `plt.subplot`, `tight` is at True by default, I settled for 0.1 divided by the width of the figure. Thanks for your help.